# How bot can interact with real Human in bot framework V4 with c#? Human Handoff

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I have made a bot in framework v4 using c#. I want my bot to interact with real human at some point. I am stuck with it. Can any one can provide a code reference so i can integrate this feature in my bot.We have a agent portal even , We don't want to use any third party. Our portal is made and bot is made but i don't know how these two connect with each other.Please any one help me out, i really need your help guys.

Comment: Please post your code, that would make things easier for anyone of us.

Comment: Which code..any dialog? Please help if have any idea

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample. I followed this and was able to implement it easily. It supports cross channel support as well just in case if you are interested

Comment: plez help me this

Comment: @shivanisingh , are you facing any issue ?

Comment: Yes i am still facing issue..can you tell me way to add button with header of chat bot @chitha kumar

Comment: @shivanisingh , You can take a look at this example to create a custom header [link](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/12.customization-minimizable-web-chat) , final demo -[link](https://microsoft.github.io/BotFramework-WebChat/12.customization-minimizable-web-chat/)

Comment: Can you help me with how to add human handoff with portal or provide me a sample..plez...i am really stuck with this and not getting any kind of solution @chithambara kumar

Comment: @shivanisingh , what issue are you facing ?, i followed the steps in the given respository it was straight forward to implement. Can you pls elaborate the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is so called "human handoff". See its document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-design-pattern-handoff-human?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) and samples [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jamiedalton/2017/08/10/microsoft-bot-framework-handing-off-to-a-human-for-agentssupervisors-with-c-and-the-botbuilder-sdk/).